# Confusion about theorem in "A Friendly Introduction to Analysis"

Tags: real-analysis

A homework problem from "A Friendly Introduction to Analysis" states: "Suppose that S is a nonempty set of real numbers. Prove that M = sup(S) IFF M is an upper bound of S and there exists a sequence {$a_n$} in S with $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n =M$" Now the way that this is posited makes me assume that this is a true statement. I don't necessarily need help proving this but it doesn't intuitively make sense to me. Define S = {$a_n | n \in \mathbb{N} $}, where $a_n = \frac{1}{n} $. Sup(S) = 1 and is an upper bound of S but there does not exist a sequence in {$a_n$} in S where $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 1$. Is this is not a valid counterexample?

Comment: no: any set containing its maximum M contains a sequence tending to that maximum: the sequence M, M, M, ...

Comment: "but there does not exist a sequence in {an} in S where limn→∞an=1"  Yes there does.  The sequence $b_n= 1$ is a sequence where $b_n \to 1$.

Comment: Remember *sets* are unordered and each element is distinct.  That is not the case of *sequences*  you wrote the set $\{\frac 1n|n\in \mathbb N\}$ as though it *looked* like a sequence but it isn't.  Writing it as a set $a_n = \frac 1n$ does not mean we have to take it in that order.    Our sequence could be $\frac 1{205}, \frac 1{3}, \frac 1{8945}, \frac 12, 1, 1, 1,1,....$ and then $1$s forever.  For that sequence (or *any* sequence) that ends with "$1$s forever" we have $\lim a_n = 1$.

Comment: “I don't necessarily need help proving this but it doesn't intuitively make sense to me.”—It's *very hard* to prove things without understanding them!

Comment: @fleablood If each element is distinct then how can the set have 1's repeating?

Comment: You don't have *set* with $1$s repeating.  You have a *sequence* with $1$ repeating.  Sequences are not sets and sets are not sequences.

Comment: A sequence is an ordered list of elements of a set, or more formally a function with a domain of the naturals and a codomain of the the set, so that each term of the sequence, that is each $a_i$ for a natural number $i$, is *a* element of the set.  There is no condition that that the $a_i$ are distinct (nor is there any requirement that the $a_i$ list all the elements of the set).

Comment: If $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3, ......., a_k, a_{k+1},......$ is a "sequence in $S$" the *ONLY* requirement is that $a_j \in S$ for all $j$.  There is *NO* requirement that the $a_j$ be different elements. (Now is there any requirement that the set have the elements in any particular order)

Comment: @fleablood I understand now, thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, the sequence $1, 1, 1, \ldots$ satisfies the condition. The problem doesn't say all the $a_n$ are distinct.

Comment: This is a valid sequence even though {1, 1, ...} is not enclosed within S?

Comment: Sequences are allowed to have repeat elements.  That's perfectly valid.  Conside $a_n = (5-b)^2$ so the sequence is $25, 16, 9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, .....$ that is obviously a perfectly valid sequence even though $\{25,16,9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, ,16,25\}$ is not "enclosed within" $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,.......\}=\mathbb N$.  Sets do *not* have order and the representation of elements are distinct.  But sequences are *ordered* incidences of elements of a set and *repetitions ARE allowed*.

Comment: Yes. Remember $S$ is _not_ a sequence. It is only a set. The sequence simply needs to be drawn from the elements of $S$. Thus  $a_1 = 1\in S$ and the _sequence_ required is $a_1, a_1, a_1,\ldots\rightarrow 1$.